# Binary file transfer Ok Win7 to Linux, not Ok Linux to Win7

Tags: java, sockets, file-upload, md5, binaryfiles

I have some client server socket code and am transferring binary files between a Windows 7 machine and a SUSE Linux box. When I transfer a file from Win7 to Linux, they end up with the same MD5 Checksum so I know they are identical. But when I transfer from Linux to Win7, the checksums don't agree, indicating that the file did not transfer properly.

Anybody run into this? I'm using ObjectOutputStreams and DataInputStreams and the code is the same on both sides.

```
 // connect socket to server socket, etc
//........

//=======================
// read the file
try {
size = file.length();
byteArr = new byte[(int) size];
dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
dis.read(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}

//=======================
// then send it
try {
oos.writeObject(byteArr);
oos.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}

// then close oos, dis, etc
```

Comment: Don't you want to try to use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,java.io.OutputStream)) ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the FileUtils lib. Does it have methods specifically for transferring binary files?

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream.read` is not guaranteed to fill the input array. It guarantees at least 1 byte is read and no more than can fit in the array, or 0 bytes if the end of file is reached, or an IOException. It may be that under linux you are not getting the whole file in one go.

Also, why are you filling a byte array and then sending it as an object? Streams are conceptualised as streams of bytes, there is no need for an array.

eg.

```
int bufferSize = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

int read;
while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
}

// flush and close everything
```

Comment: I did forget to mention that the byte count of the file after being sent to the Win7 box is the same as it is on the Linux box, so it *seems* like the entire file is being sent. Also, InputStream.read may not fill the input array but InputStream.read(byte[], 0, byte[].length) should fill the entire array, and in practice, it does.